# Set backgroud color based around database call

Tags: java, android

I have the following method that only checks if a Sqlite database has data, but I don't like how the code looks

```
 private void comprobarColorActual() {
        try {
            if (cantidadRegistrosBodega() > 1) {
                colorBodega.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D5F5E3"));
            }
            if (cantidaRegistrosMaestro() > 1) {
                colorMaestro.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D5F5E3"));
            }
            if (cantidaRegistrosProductos() > 1) {
                colorProducto.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D5F5E3"));
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            Log.i("NumberFormatException", e.toString());
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.i("RuntimeException", e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, in my opinion, you should add more details of what the code does, and since the code is not compiling, it's really hard to do a proper code review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `else if`, whenever applicable. I don't understand the names can't say for certain if these conditions are exclusive.

Ensure you method name is meaningful. `colorActual` in english is not really meaningful.

Use a wrapper for all your Logging, it will help if you move environments and need to change how you make your LOG statements.

`Log.i` usually means 'info', `Log.e` would be for errors. If you don't want to handle these errors (and it looks like they shouldn't occur), add a `throws` statement instead.

Avoid magic numbers & magic strings, instead declare static final variables at the top of the class, or use a properties file.

Example refactored code:

```
private static final String BACKGROUND_COLOR = "#D5F5E3";

private void comprobarColorActual() throws NumberFormatException {
    private String backgroundColor;

    if (cantidadRegistrosBodega() > 1) {
        colorBodega.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(BACKGROUND_COLOR));
    } else if (cantidaRegistrosMaestro() > 1) {
        colorMaestro.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(BACKGROUND_COLOR));
    } else if (cantidaRegistrosProductos() > 1) {
        colorProducto.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(BACKGROUND_COLOR));
    }
}
```